Han-Lin Lecture Notes on Elliptic Differential Equations, proving two inequalities are equivalent
I am reading http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~anprin/EllipticEq-Han-Lin.pdf this lecture note, and in p.77 (Theorem 4.4) it is written that the inequality $$ 1-\frac{1}{q}-\frac{\beta+1}{(\beta+2)\chi}\geq 0$$
where $\chi=n/(n-2)$, is equivalent to the inequality $$ \beta+2 \leq \frac{q(n-2)}{n-2q}.$$
But I'm having a hard time showing this. I tried to start from the latter one to get the former one. We have $$\frac{q}{n-2q}=\frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{nq}{n-2q}=\frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{1}{q}-\frac{2}{n}} $$
so the second inequality is equivalent to $$\beta+2 \leq \frac{1}{\chi(\frac{1}{q}-\frac{2}{n})},$$
or $$ \frac{1}{(\beta+2)\chi}\geq \frac{1}{q}-\frac{2}{n}.$$
I can't see how this becomes the first inequality..

Note that $1/\chi = 1-2/n$. So
\begin{align}&\frac{1}{(\beta+2)\chi}\geq \frac{1}{q}-\frac{2}{n} =\dfrac{1}{q}+\dfrac{1}{\chi}-1\\ \Longleftrightarrow & \left(\frac{1}{\beta+2}-1\right)\frac{1}{\chi}+1-\frac{1}{q} =1 - \dfrac{1}{q}-\dfrac{\beta+1}{\beta+2} \ge 0\end{align}
